# VLC plays network stream from the past?

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, vlc, raspberry-pi, netcat

I have a working h264 video stream server solution where I pipe the video output to netcat.
The streaming server is a Raspberry Pi with a camera module

```
raspivid -t 999999 -w 300 -h 300 -hf -fps 20 -o - | nc -l 9999
```

Under client-linux, when piping netcat output to mplayer, I get almost no video delay (~100ms).

```
nc *ip* 9999 | mplayer -fps 200 -demuxer h264es -
```

It's just what I need. Now, because I want also a Windows-client, I tried to play the stream on VLC.

Media->open network stream.

URL: tcp://ip:port

more options->edit options-> "network-caching=0 :demux=h264"

After pressing PLAY, the video stream starts immediately BUT it is about 12 seconds in the past ?! If I start the client just after starting the server stream, the lag is few seconds but the video is really slow and after some time the delay is again about 12 seconds.

I believe this is only a config question here in the client-vlc side. Do you have any ideas where and what should I look for ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the way you run `raspvid` makes recording starts **before** a client connects to `nc`. Try the following:

```
raspivid -t 999999 -w 300 -h 300 -hf -fps 20 -l -o tcp://0.0.0.0:9999
```